# How to delete a folder using iRODS?

Tags: icommand

I know copying a folder is something like this:

`iput -r <folder_in_local_directory> <location_on_iRODS>`

But how to delete a folder which exists on iRODS?

Answer (score 1):

I found, the answer is: `irm -r <location_on_iRODS>` to remove the collection recursively

Comment: you can use `irmtrash` to empty the trash as well.